# call focusout on parent of input element

Tags: jquery, events

This is my html

```
   <div class="parent">
    <input class="text"/>
    <input class="text"/>
    </div>
```

How do i use jQuery's $.on() ie delegation to detect when the parent div (.parent) looses focus, it seems all the focusout events are fired on the inputs only

## update:

the reason i need this solution is: the parent div is suppose to be a temporal element on the page and must stay hidden when the user clicks outside of it

Comment: That's because a `div` can't have focus. Well, unless it has a `tabindex` set (I believe).

Comment: What does a div with focus look like?

Answer (score 0):

(`class="parent` should be `class="parent"`)

The focusout-Event is working just fine for me. A div can only get focus with a tabindex (in HTML 5)

Take a look at:
http://jsfiddle.net/m2gUm/

Just click on the first input and then press three times the tab-key. If the count is 3 in the end, then the div got (un-)focused successfully. (In Opera I enabled a option to highlight focused elements and the div was highlighted after the second press of the tab key)

Of course you can do the same thing with .on():

```
$('.parent').on('focusout', function()
{
    // ...
});
```

Comment: The number of counts should appear after clicking on the first input and then pressing tab. I tested it with firefox and opera. 


About your update: Did I understood it right? You have a div with inputs inside and when the user clicks outside of the div it should disappear? So something similar like bootstrap modals? (When you click outside of them, they disappear) http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: similar except the window will not appear as an overlay but inline, right after clicking an element that triggers it. Maybe i should just use a model since it easier to manage